# Why do certain Input Components do a GET_MANY query when a option is selected?

Tags: react-admin

I have a noticed that a GET_MANY query is called when I select an option in SelectInput and RadioButtonGroupInput when wrapped by a ReferenceInput . I'm not sure how to handle these queries (what needs to be returned) as there is a filter being sent to the backend. What is being expected to be returned?